# Count list for any object

Tags: haskell

I have a data structure like that:

```
data MultTree b = DataNode b | IndexNode Int Int [MultTree b] deriving (Show)
```

For working with that structure recursively I need a function that counts the objects of a list. Is there a universial one for any type of object?

My compiler does accept only Num as a parameter:

```
countList :: (Num) => [a] -> a
countList [] = 0
countList (x:xs) = 1 + countList xs
```

Comment: What about just `length`?

Comment: Well, you are right that would be an option. On the other hand I would like to see how I could do that function by myself

Comment: And remove the `(Num) =>`. The way you've written it looks illegal, and a Typeclass restriction is unnecessary since you never use the elements directly. Just change the signature to `countList :: [a] -> Integer`, since you have a list of anything, and want to return a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of the function is wrong. You want to take it a list of an arbitraty type `a` and return an integer:

```
countList :: [a] -> Int
```